# "ERROR: cannot copy to non-directory" when copying to WORKDIR?

Tags: bash, docker

I am simply trying to copy all the contents of the current directory into the docker image. Why is the *WORKDIR* not allowed as a destination?

```
from ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR .
ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN echo "HOME is $HOME"
COPY  ./setup-python.sh ./
COPY  ./* ./
```

> ERROR: cannot copy to non-directory: > /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cytt3i5m23b6ce9iciljwb3c7/merged/lib

Note: I have also tried without the backslash and it results in  the same error.

```
COPY  ./setup-python.sh .
COPY  ./* .
```

Comment: What was `WORKDIR .` supposed to do anyway`

Comment: @tkausl I did not find any particular documentation on what `WORKDIR` were _supposed_ to be set to . So I assumed  -incorrectly- that there were some default directory available.

Comment: `I did not find any particular documentation on what WORKDIR were supposed to be set to` Its supposed to be set to the directory you actually want to use as working directory. The default is `/` IIRC.

Comment: OK - thx I'm happily moving forward finally . nice to do some local testing instead of depending solely on the cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error it seems that `.` were not a valid `WORKDIR`? I just made one up instead:

```
WORKDIR=/usr/build   # totally arbitrary
```

At least the build is progressing now.

**Update**  The correct `COPY` command is now dead simple

```
COPY  . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error when you try to copy a directory from the source over a something other than a directory in the destination.

```
WORKDIR .
```

is generally going to put you at the root of a Linux file system, i.e. `/`. For example, with

```
ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime
```

you have created `/etc/localtime` as a symbolic link. That is both `./etc/localtime` and `/etc/localtime`. If you have in your local directory (`.` on the build host) a directory `./etc/localtime/` then you will get this error.

It could be something else, of course. Your base image is `ubuntu:20.04`, which has `/bin/`, `/lib/`, and `/sbin` as symbolic links, so if you have any of those directories in `.` then you will get this error.

By setting `WORKDIR=/usr/build` you have changed the meaning of `.` as a destination. Now instead of copying your host directory to `/` you are copying it to `/usr/build` which is empty, so there are no conflicts to worry about.