# Docker ERROR: failed to solve: cannot copy to non-directory when copying to

Tags: docker, copy

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1774460/285886), but when copying from a previous `FROM` target ([source](https://github.com/sqitchers/docker-sqitch/blob/v1.4.0-maint/Dockerfile#L61)):

```
COPY --from=sqitch-build /app .
```

This worked fine until recently, when it started emitting this error:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: cannot copy to non-directory: /var/lib/buildkit/runc-overlayfs/cachemounts/buildkit3355209005/bin
```

I tried this, but got the same error:

```
COPY --from=sqitch-build /app /
```

I'm not sure what it doesn't like. I can work around it by making a separate `COPY` for each subdirectory:

```
COPY --from=sqitch-build /app/lib /lib
COPY --from=sqitch-build /app/bin /bin
```

But that seems unnecessary. Has something changed recently in Docker to impact the rules for COPY statements?

Comment: Does this post help : https://superuser.com/questions/1774460/error-cannot-copy-to-non-directory-when-copying-to-workdir?rq=1? See also [WORKDIR doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely what has changed is your base Docker image. Recent Linux distributions have replaced the `/bin` directory with a symbolic link `/bin -> /usr/bin`. Your error and solution are consistent with `/` having such a link.

```
COPY --from=sqitch-build /app /
```

fails because Docker will not copy `/app/bin` (a directory) over `/bin` a symbolic link.

```
COPY --from=sqitch-build /app/bin /bin
```

succeeds because Docker will follow the symlink on the target `/bin` and copy the source `/app/bin` into the target `/usr/bin`.

Comment: I had no idea that "Recent Linux distributions have replaced the `/bin` directory with a symbolic link `/bin -> /usr/bin`." With that knowledge, I found [this buildkit issue](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/2626), which highlights the lack of clarity on the handling of symlinks. Good to know, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was that I didn't set the **WORKDIR** in Dockerfile

The example using this operator in Python project:

```
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /app
```

Comment: Explaining HOW to set this would go a long way towards making this a better answer. Currently it is a possibly helpful comment. Please EDIT your post to improve, expand, and clarify it.